# Resolving git repo with master branch and a second branch name MASTER

Tags: git

When switching back from a local branch, I accidentally checked out a new branch, MASTER, and pushed it to origin. Now the repo has master and MASTER as branches. How do I safely rename MASTER and rebase it into master?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really no need to rename it. Simply merge or rebase your new changes in MASTER onto master, then delete the MASTER branch.

- `git merge master MASTER` will add a merge commit to `master`, along with the history of individual commits.
- If you'd rather do a rebase, use `git rebase master MASTER`.

After either one of those, run `git branch -d MASTER` to delete your local MASTER branch. To delete the remote branch, run `git push origin :MASTER` ([via this page](http://github.com/guides/remove-a-remote-branch)). And be sure to push it all to origin afterwards.

**Edit** If you really do want to rename it, like if you maintain links to your topic branches, delete the remote branch, rename it locally using `git branch -M MASTER foobar` and push it to the remote.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. I'm still learning git and really love what I've seen so far. I'll let you know how it goes.

Thanks again!

Comment: Yep. That worked perfectly. Thank you so much! You just resolved a major headache.